# How to hide certain id/class in html if variable of an array is empty

Tags: php, arrays, tabs

Im new to php.

Hide tab If that array varible is empty.

```
<ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
                <li class="active"><a href="#eng" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-tree"></i> English</a>
                </li>

                </li>
                <li class=""><a href="#cho" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-car"></i> Chords</a>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="eng">
                    <div class="lyrics-body-txt">
                    <div class="english"> `<?php echo $song["eng"]; ?>`

                    </div></div>
                </div>
                 <div class="tab-pane fade" id="cho">
                    <div class="lyrics-body-txt">
                    <div class="chords"> `<?php echo $song["chords"]; ?>`

                    </div></div>
                </div></div></div>'
```

"english"   => "bla bla bla bla bla",

"chords"    => "",      ---- This is empty

So i want to hide that chords tab when ever the chords variable is empty

Comment: Where's your attempted code?

Comment: if(isset($_GET['sID'])) {
  $listaLyric = strip_bad_chars( $_GET['sID'] );
  $song = $listaLyrics[$listaLyric];
 }        Array : $listaLyrics = array( "english" => "bla bla bla bla bla", "chords" => "", );

Comment: put html code in `if` condition. `if(!empty($song["chords"]);`

Comment: I want hide the tab of chords. I have two tabs english and chords so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="eng">
                <div class="lyrics-body-txt">
                <div class="english"> <?php echo $song["eng"]; ?>

                </div></div>
            </div>
            <?php 
            if($song["chords"] != '')
            {
                ?>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="cho">
                    <div class="lyrics-body-txt">
                        <div class="chords"> <?php echo $song["chords"]; ?></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php
            }
            ?>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide the div just add the hidden class

```
<div class="chords <?php if(empty($song["chords"]) echo 'hidden'; ?>">
```

If you don't want it:

```
<?php 
     if(!empty($song["chords"])) {
         echo '
               <div class="tab-pane fade" id="cho">
                    <div class="lyrics-body-txt">
                    <div class="chords"> '.$song["chords"].'

                    </div></div>
                </div>
         ';
     } 
?>
```

Comment: i dont want to print 'not available'. I want to remove the whole tab

Comment: hey i tried it but it says: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{'

Comment: I want to hide this  <li class=""><a href="#cho" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-car"></i> Chords</a>
                </li>